# Contain webhook in my client

Tags: java, apache-spark, servlets, twilio

I have a java client that reads and writes to a local postegresql database. The application receives SMS messages from Twilio through a webhook. Right now I use spark in the client and utilize ngrok to create a URL of localhost that twilio can use as the webhook. How can I scale this to production? I would like to keep the webhook as part of the client, so I can receive messages in real time instead of periodically requesting the messages from a web server.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?
is it how to setup the application so it no longer needs a 'localhost'' url?

Comment: Are you asking how to deploy your application to a server?